# Issue Related to Dynamically Created Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have added Following HTML in the Form:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblFlightDetails">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="ASPTableHeader">
                <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lblFrom" Text="From" CssClass="LabelFont"></dx:ASPxLabel>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="ASPTableHeader">
                <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lblTo" Text="To" CssClass="LabelFont"></dx:ASPxLabel>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="ASPTableHeader">
                <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lblFlight" Text="Flight/Airline" CssClass="LabelFont"></dx:ASPxLabel>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="ASPTableHeader">
                <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lblDate" Text="Date" CssClass="LabelFont"></dx:ASPxLabel>
            </asp:TableCell>
                   </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

Now from Serverside code.. I have added 3 rows dynamically.. when ever page gets Postback.. all dynamically added rows get disappear..
How can i get the dynamically added rows after postback??

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Dynamically created controls need to be re-created on *every* postback. This is best done in the `OnInit` event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but what about data.. that was added in those rows? how can i get data added in dyanmic Rows??

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani - Once re-added on postback, you should be able to access the added values after the load event has run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-add those rows every time for every postback. You are responsible.

(Eventually you might get away with viewstate, but it's ugly)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but what about data.. that was added in those rows?